# Getting error in adding excisions of sample code

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Hi i have tried too much on compiling the code which i have created by learning forge tutorial and i want to add some additional extension in viewer like this code sample_https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo but every time i have same error. also cant find at which line code get an error. can anyone ans? thankyou

i just want to load this data to model and after that i want to place some sensor and camera in model want to see live footage and sensor data.

Comment: Can you please provide more details about the error you obtain ? Or some part of your code ? It will help us identify where is the problem and maybe how to resolve this. Without more information, it's hard to help you ...

Comment: @peter  here is code link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tRAWJxPRlFjywwXsaf0of4FozBnRw_yv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should not share a link to your code stored on a cloud drive. Add errors message and eventually some part of code that you wrote, as **text** (here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help you edit and format your question)

Comment: Please translate the revit file with "advanced": {
                "generateMasterViews": true
            } in request body inside format object.